# SQLAlchemy sqlite3 remove value from JSON column on multiple rows with different JSON values

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, orm

Say I have an id column that is saved as `ids JSON NOT NULL` using SQLAlchemy, and now I want to delete an id from this column. I'd like to do several things at once:

1. query only the rows who have this specific ID
2. delete this ID from all rows it appears in
3. a bonus, if possible - delete the row if the ID list is now empty.

For the query, something like this:
`db.query(models.X).filter(id in list(models.X.ids))` should work.
now, I'd rather avoid iterating over each query and then send an update request as it can be multiple rows. Is there any elegant way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: So `ids` is a JSON array, like `'[1, 2, 3]'`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yup, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: Not sure that your suggested solution works properly since you are building an SQL query here, your rows are not mapped yet to ORM instances at this point. What you are likely searching for are the json functions https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: What is the structure of `X`?

Comment: Other thing is that you could do 1 and 2 in one query (UPDATE). But 3 will be another query (DELETE).

Comment: @snakecharmerb `X` contains `X.ids` and other irrelevant values

Comment: @jossefaz could you give an example? i was under the impression that a simple `.update{"ids": ..."}` would not suffice

Comment: I posted an answer (did not test it yet but the id is here...let me know if it works for you and if not we will try to get to the right syntax together

Answer (score 1):

For the search and remove remove part you can use [`json_remove` function](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jrm) (from SQLLite built-in functions)

```py
from sqlalchemy import func 

db.query(models.X).update({'ids': func.json_remove(models.X.ids,f'$[{TARGET_ID}]') })
```

Here replace TARGET_ID by the targeted id.
Now this will update the row 'silently' (wether or not this id is present in the array).

If you want to first check if target id is in the column: you can query first all rows containing the target id with [`json_extract`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex) query (calling `.all()` method and then remove those ids with an `.update()` call.

But this will cost you double amount of queries (less performant).

For the delete part, you can use the [json_array_length](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jarraylen) built-in function

```py
from sqlalchemy import func 

db.query(models.X).filter(func.json_array_length(models.X.ids) == 0).delete()
```

FYI : Not sure that you can do both in one query, and even if possible, I would not do it for clean syntax, logging and monitoring reasons.

Comment: thanks! currently, this syntax doesn't work for me - the update query is successful but the target ID is not removed

Comment: did you commit ?

Comment: yup. my flow is deleting this id from a different table - > updating a table with lyour command. the id is deleted successfully from the first table, but not from the list on the second

Comment: this sounds more like another issue in the code, not related to your question

Comment: @Omri.B : if you continue having trouble on this, we can move to chat and I will do my best to help you solve this issue....we speak same language also ;-)

Comment: I've figured out the issue. In my sqlite server (sqlite3), `json_removes` does not remove the given number, but, the number at the index of the given number. So, in the documentation it seems like we both thought, but it actually isn't. Unsure if this is the expected behavior, the documentation makes it seem like it is not. So I'm not sure this is the way to go :(

Comment: sounds weird indeed. let me know if you want to jump to chat